# Ansible: How to copy file from `files` directory to `templates` directory in a role directory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want to write an Ansible task to copy file from `files` directory to `templates` directory.

For example, I have an Ansible role named `data` and inside this role's directory

```
~/data$ tree
.
├── defaults
├── tasks
├── templates
└── files
    └── application.j2
```

So I have a file inside the `files` directory named `application.j2`

I want to copy this file `application.j2` into the `templates` directory using an Ansible task.

I've tried to use the below task in the `src:` path I use `files/application.j2` but I don't know what I should write in `dest:` path.

```yaml
- name: Transfer File.
   copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: 
  with_fileglob:
    - "files/application.j2"
```

Ansible: How to copy file from `files` directory to `templates` directory in a role directory?

Comment: Was this question not already answered? As far as I remember it was recommended to use `mv` and highlighted that Ansible is not intended for altering the code base of the files it is executing itself, means the task files, playbook, templates, etc.

Comment: could you provide me with this

Comment: Since the question text is a copy a paste from an other question, do you mean the link where it was copied from? Or do you mean the comments where it was answered? Furthermore, what about to use the `mv` command?

Comment: ok how to use mv command in local role directory can you provide me with task mv file in local

Comment: Do you mean like `mv files/app* templates/` or `cp files/app* templates/`?

Comment: ok like this but task in ansible . i want to copyy file between same ansible role directory –

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76333200/ansible-task-to-copy-file-from-files-directory-to-templates-directory-in-a-role?noredirect=1#comment134606460_76333200 Please respect site rules and do not ask the same question twice. Edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume one like to

- Copy files with patterns between different folders
- Let the task run on the Ansible Control Node only

A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost 
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Copy each file that matches the given pattern
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "templates/{{ item.split('.') | first | basename }}.j2"
    with_fileglob:
      - "files/app*.j2"
```

will result into the requested output.

**Similar Q&A**

For a more detailed explanation see the answer under

- [Looping in Ansible templates directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314533/6771046)
- [Ansible: Copy files with wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116534/)

Comment: no i didn't mean this . i want to copyy file between same ansible role directory

Comment: That's exactly what the task is doing. Can you explain in more detail why do you think it is not? Furthermore, you've provided an example task with some missing functionality which I've just extended to make it work.

Comment: this task it will be beside another tasks so i cant wirte - hosts: localhost 
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

Comment: I've just provided a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe you can have a look into the article.

Comment: Furthermore regarding "_will be beside another tasks so I cant write_", technically it would be possible, so of course you could, see [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution).  Maybe you can have a look into the documention.

Comment: Regarding "_I cant write - hosts: localhost_" and since you like and need to [Control where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html), maybe you can have a look into the documentation and use just `delegate_to: localhost run_one: true`.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Copy files from `files` directory to `templates` directory in a role."***

Given the project for testing

```bash
shell> pwd
/scratch/tmp7/test-359
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
├── roles
│   └── data
│       ├── defaults
│       ├── files
│       │   └── application.j2
│       ├── tasks
│       └── templates
├── roles2
│   └── roleX
└── roles3
    └── roleY
```

A: I read this question as: ***"What is the directory of a role?"***

If you're running a task in a role you can use the special variable [*role_path*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-role_path). But, this is not the case here. You want to copy the files inside the roles from a task in a playbook. Declare a dictionary with the roles and files you want to transfer between the directories *files* and *templates*

```yaml
  transfer_files:
    data:
      - application.j2
```

There might be more directories in [DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path). For example,

```ini
shell> grep roles_path ansible.cfg 
roles_path = $PWD/roles:$PWD/roles2:$PWD/roles3
```

Get the variable

```yaml
  my_roles_path: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_roles_path:
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles2
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles3
```

Find all roles

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: "{{ my_roles_path }}"
        file_type: directory
        depth: 1
      register: my_roles_out
```

and declare the variables

```yaml
  my_roles: "{{ my_roles_out.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
  my_roles_dict: "{{ dict(my_roles|map('basename')|
                          zip(my_roles|map('dirname'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_roles:
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles/data
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles2/roleX
  - /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles3/roleY

  my_roles_dict:
    data: /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles
    roleX: /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles2
    roleY: /scratch/tmp7/test-359/roles3
```

Now, you can copy the file(s)

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ item.1 }}"
        dest: "{{ role_path }}/templates/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ transfer_files|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      vars:
        role_path: "{{ my_roles_dict[item.0.key] }}/{{ item.0.key }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
├── roles
│   └── data
│       ├── defaults
│       ├── files
│       │   └── application.j2
│       ├── tasks
│       └── templates
│           └── application.j2   <-- from files
├── roles2
│   └── roleX
└── roles3
    └── roleY
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_roles_path: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') }}"
    my_roles: "{{ my_roles_out.files|map(attribute='path') }}"
    my_roles_dict: "{{ dict(my_roles|map('basename')|
                            zip(my_roles|map('dirname'))) }}"

    transfer_files:
      data:
        - application.j2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_roles_path

    - find:
        paths: "{{ my_roles_path }}"
        file_type: directory
        depth: 1
      register: my_roles_out

    - debug:
        var: my_roles
    - debug:
        var: my_roles_dict

    - copy:
        src: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ item.1 }}"
        dest: "{{ role_path }}/templates/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ transfer_files|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      vars:
        role_path: "{{ my_roles_dict[item.0.key] }}/{{ item.0.key }}"
```